# Is it possible to call JavaScript functions from C using QuickJS?

Tags: javascript, c, quickjs

Let's say I have a JavaScript file containing multiple functions like this:

```
function a(input){
    return [input,input*2]
}

function b(input){
   return {
       message:`Hello, ${input}!`
   }
}
```

Is it possible to use QuickJS to call these functions from a C program and to store the returned values in a C array/struct?

Comment: https://github.com/taskie/quickjs-exercise/blob/master/simple/simple.c